# How to send a mail to a person after inserting data from data loader command line interface suceeds

Tags: email, data-loader, commandline

I am using data loader command line to insert data into salesforce and scheduled for everyday using windows svheduler.

I want to send a mail to a specific mail id whether this job succeeds/fails.

How to do this ?

Comment: Are you inserting data in a single object or multiple objects?

Also, do you want to send emails for every batch the data loader processes or the entire job at once?

Comment: I am inserting data into single object ie standard Account object. I running a nightly script from a database which gives a csv file, i am inserting that csv file into account object everyday on a nightly basis, so i am using data loader command line and windows scheduler. I want an email to be sent everytime the script runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using CLI for data loader it means you must have used process.bat and you are aware about windows batch files.

TO send email you will need to modify process.bat or create new .bat file and call to process.bat from your new .bat file.

After that write steps to send email from CLI.

Here is reference link that shows how you can send email from .bat file.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038926/how-to-send-a-simple-email-from-a-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I can think of is to send email from the Trigger written on the Account object. So as soon as your batch job loads Account records, the trigger would be fired and an email would be sent to you. The downside is that you will get emails for every "batch" of records that will be inserted. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think there are few issues with this. 1) It will send too many email if you upload big chunk. 2) If you insert data from UI then also it will send email.